# Convert JSON into PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

We use Zendesk at work and I am using some PHP & CURL provided by them to display data. However the Data I get comes back like this if I use (json_decode($output,true)) :

> array(4) { ["satisfaction_ratings"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(10) { ["url"]=> string(83) "https://sessioncam1384769452.zendesk.com/api/v2/satisfaction_ratings/183839137.json" ["id"]=> int(183839137) ["assignee_id"]=> int(551715796) ["group_id"]=> int(21464896) ["requester_id"]=> int(543065527) ["ticket_id"]=> int(6) ["score"]=> string(4) "good" ["created_at"]=> string(20) "2013-11-22T12:57:50Z" ["updated_at"]=> string(20) "2013-11-22T12:57:50Z" ["comment"]=> string(3) "hey" } [1]=> array(10) { ["url"]=> string(83) "https://sessioncam1384769452.zendesk.com/api/v2/satisfaction_ratings/180738208.json" ["id"]=> int(180738208) ["assignee_id"]=> int(551715796) ["group_id"]=> int(21464896) ["requester_id"]=> int(543078357) ["ticket_id"]=> int(7) ["score"]=> string(4) "good" ["created_at"]=> string(20) "2013-11-22T13:16:11Z" ["updated_at"]=> string(20) "2013-11-22T13:16:11Z" ["comment"]=> string(5) "heyyy" } } ["next_page"]=> NULL ["previous_page"]=> NULL ["count"]=> int(2) }

If I use just json_decode($output) I get:

> object(stdClass)#1 (4) { ["satisfaction_ratings"]=> array(2) { [0]=>
>   object(stdClass)#2 (10) { ["url"]=> string(83)
>   "https://sessioncam1384769452.zendesk.com/api/v2/satisfaction_ratings/183839137.json"
>   ["id"]=> int(183839137) ["assignee_id"]=> int(551715796)
>   ["group_id"]=> int(21464896) ["requester_id"]=> int(543065527)
>   ["ticket_id"]=> int(6) ["score"]=> string(4) "good" ["created_at"]=>
>   string(20) "2013-11-22T12:57:50Z" ["updated_at"]=> string(20)
>   "2013-11-22T12:57:50Z" ["comment"]=> string(3) "hey" } [1]=>
>   object(stdClass)#3 (10) { ["url"]=> string(83)
>   "https://sessioncam1384769452.zendesk.com/api/v2/satisfaction_ratings/180738208.json"
>   ["id"]=> int(180738208) ["assignee_id"]=> int(551715796)
>   ["group_id"]=> int(21464896) ["requester_id"]=> int(543078357)
>   ["ticket_id"]=> int(7) ["score"]=> string(4) "good" ["created_at"]=>
>   string(20) "2013-11-22T13:16:11Z" ["updated_at"]=> string(20)
>   "2013-11-22T13:16:11Z" ["comment"]=> string(5) "heyyy" } }
>   ["next_page"]=> NULL ["previous_page"]=> NULL ["count"]=> int(2) }

Essentially what I'm trying to do is just get a list of the "comment" sections. I tried to use this line for the json_decode($output): print $data->satisfaction_ratings->comment;

But that doesnt work, can anyone assist with getting just the one array value out?, I am not able to change the JSON that comes out of the system. The JSON before it runs through jason_decode is:

> string(666)
>   "{"satisfaction_ratings":[{"url":"https://sessioncam1384769452.zendesk.com/api/v2/satisfaction_ratings/183839137.json","id":183839137,"assignee_id":551715796,"group_id":21464896,"requester_id":543065527,"ticket_id":6,"score":"good","created_at":"2013-11-22T12:57:50Z","updated_at":"2013-11-22T12:57:50Z","comment":"hey"},{"url":"https://sessioncam1384769452.zendesk.com/api/v2/satisfaction_ratings/180738208.json","id":180738208,"assignee_id":551715796,"group_id":21464896,"requester_id":543078357,"ticket_id":7,"score":"good","created_at":"2013-11-22T13:16:11Z","updated_at":"2013-11-22T13:16:11Z","comment":"heyyy"}],"next_page":null,"previous_page":null,"count":2}"

If anyone can help that would be great

Comment: You can treat those decoded objects as if they were arrays anyways. `$obj['satisfaction_ratings'][0]['url']` and whatnot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access that *specific* element, so you can use the following:

```
echo $data->satisfaction_ratings[0]->comment;
echo $data->satisfaction_ratings[1]->comment;
```

If you're setting the second parameter for `json_decode()` as `TRUE`, then you need to use the array syntax to access the comment:

```
echo $data['satisfaction_ratings'][0]['comment'];
echo $data['satisfaction_ratings'][1]['comment'];
```

If there are multiple comments, and you want to display all of them, use a loop:

```
foreach ($data['satisfaction_ratings'] as $comment) {
    echo $comment['comment'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Amal, would there be an easy way to work through the 2nd level? (so what im saying is to go through from 0 to whatever the last number is?)

Comment: Thanks alot, I've got it now, looking at your answer it was fairly simple all along, i'd just gotten confused.

Comment: @Stefan: Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 1):

Just the comments, as an array:

```
$data = json_decode($output, true);

$comments = array_map(
    function ($s) { return $s['comment']; },
    $data['satisfaction_ratings']
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @bishop, ive used the other answer now though

Comment: Just don't assume that because ThereIsMoreThanOneWayToDoIt that YouShouldDoItEveryWhichWay. There is usually a *good* way to do it and you should do it that way :)