# Extract image URLs from Instagram media feed with JSON and PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode, file-get-contents

I am trying to extract the different image URLs from the Instagram media feed:

```
<?php
$insta = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/apple/media/');
$json = json_decode($insta, true);
foreach($json->items->images as $instaimage){
echo $instaimage['url']['standard_resolution'];
}
?>
```

> **Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Output from https://www.instagram.com/apple/media:

```
{"items": [{"id": "1595195862853610235_5821462185", "code": "BYjRi-Aj-r7", "user": {"id": "5821462185", "full_name": "apple", "profile_picture": "https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/20635165_1942203892713915_5464937638928580608_a.jpg", "username": "apple"}, "images": {"thumbnail": {"width": 150, "height": 150, "url": "https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/21149363_134897580459546_4211564004683808768_n.jpg"}, "low_resolution": {"width": 320, "height": 320, "url": "https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/21149363_134897580459546_4211564004683808768_n.jpg"}, "standard_resolution": {"width": 640, "height": 640, "url": "https://scontent-bru2-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/21149363_134897580459546_4211564004683808768_n.jpg"}}, "created_time": "1504382187", "caption": {"id": "17887744828075147", "text": "\u201cI will do almost anything to get the shot I envision...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON into PHP Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147993/convert-json-into-php-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this one will be helpful. There are few issues with your code.

> **1.** `json_decode($insta,true)` will give you an array instead of an object, because here you are passing second parameter as `true`.
>
> **2.** `$json->items` contains array of objects of `items` instead of single `items` key.

```
$insta = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/apple/media/');
$json = json_decode($insta);
foreach($json->items as $instaimage)
{
    echo $instaimage->images->standard_resolution->url;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: @rainerbrunotte welcome... friend.. glad to help you... :)